# I have a grid of $9\times8$. How many ways are there of putting $8$ chips on this grid such that no two chips are on the same line?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

### Question

I have a grid of $9\times8$. How many ways are there of putting $8$ chips on this grid such that no two chips are on the same line?
*[When I say put chips on the grid, I mean on the intersections]*

### My Approach

This is what I've done so far, I approached this from THREE different angles and all THREE seem to give me different results.

**Approach-I**
Put a chip on one of the $9$ lines that are parallel to each other. For the first line, I have $8$ options (there are $8$ intersections on this line). Moving to the next, I have $7$ options. I keep doing this until I've placed $7$ chips. Now I have two lines on which I can place my last chip, and only $1$ option on either of those. Thus, answer
$$\boxed{8! \times 2}$$

**Approach-II**
Do the same, but Now moving on the $8$ lines that are parallel to each other. I have $9$ options on the first line, $8$ on the second,..... and $2$ on the last line. Now, my answer is $$\boxed{9!}$$

**Approach-III**
Count the possible intersections.

- For the first chip I have $9\times8=72$ possibilities.
- For the second, I'd suppose that two lines got eliminated, so that's $8\times7=56$ possibilities.

I did that for all $8$ chips and get
$$\boxed{\prod_{i=1}^{8} i(i+1)}$$
Which is a ridiculously huge number

To be honest I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or which cases I'm counting more than once. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one in each of the 8 columns.
Let $\{4,9,2,7,2,1,3,5\}$ denote the case where you put the first column chip in row $4$, the second column chip in row $9$, etc...

The amount of possible cases is basically the amount of size $8$ permutations of the numbers $1$ to $9$ like the one above. Hence there are

$$\frac{9!}{(9-8)!} = 362880$$

cases.

Comment: Ok, I think I kinda get it. It's like the case B I described right? I now know what the correct answer is, would you happen to know what Ii'm doing wrong in the other two cases?

Comment: In c) you construct each case multiple times, because you can choose any combination of intersections in many different orders

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio In a) you start by selecting a row, and all the cases that you count have a chip in that row, even though the row could be empty.

Comment: So in A I could still do the same that in B but by first doing 9C8 to choose 8 out of the 9 lines?

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio Yes that would work

Answer (score 1):

The chips are probably assumed to be identical, so you are in fact counting available intersections on the grid.

For A, notice that you will only get the chip arrangements where one of the lines $8$ and $9$ is empty. However, any of the lines $1, \ldots, 9$ can be empty.

You have $9$ ways to pick the empty line. Now you have $8$ ways to place a chip on the first of the remaining lines, $7$ ways to place the second chip on the second of the remaining lines, and so on, until the last chip will have only one available intersection on the last remaining line.

The result is $9!$.

Your B is correct, since all of the $8$ lines will have one chip placed on them.

For C, notice that you are choosing the same intersections in several ways, as there is no way to track where you started putting the chips.